# Return values for specific cells

Tags: excel, vba

On sheet2, I have a column of insurance numbers in rows A1:A500.
On sheet1 is the insurance number and additional information that needs to come over to sheet2.

I'm trying to look at cell A1 in sheet2, then compare that insurance number with all of the occurrences on sheet1 and copy the data into sheet2. Then go to sheet2 Cell A2 and continue this process until I've exhausted all of the insurance numbers in sheet2 cells A1:A500.

I tried to make cell A2 static, and pull directly. I used the range command but it hasn't worked.

I recorded a macro, and this is what I have below.
When I record the macro, I copy the information in cell A1 and not cell A1.
I've changed the data from the insurance number to "ABC" on the first occurrence, and "123" on the second occurrence.

```vb
Sub Insurance_Check()
'
' Insurance_Check Macro
' Returns all of the insurance numbers
'

'
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$K$25720").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:= _
        "ABC"
    Range("A3:K25720").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("E6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$K$25720").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:= _
        "123"
    Range("A10605:K10606").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("E9").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$K$25720").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:= _
        "456"
    Range("A358:K362").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("E11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

[A picture of sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcvCa.png)
Under insurance claim, are sample insurance 1, 2, and 3.
If in Sheet2, Cell A1 I have "Sample Insurance1" I should have a return on sheet2 with all of the values from sheet1 that are "Sample Insurance1".
Then next should be the values for "Sample Insurance2" and so on.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Instead, include the actual code so that people can copy/paste it if they want to.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Unless I misunderstand what you want to do, `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH` may do the job. Some mock data would be useful.

Comment: Tried that but in this "ABC", "123", and "456" could bring in multiple lines back. The sheet it pulls from has about 40k lines. Index match brings the first, Index aggregate doesn't really fix any of it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. This will look through SelectRange and compare it with CompareRange. If SelectRange's Cell matches CompareRange's Cell, it will copy the cell next to CompareRange (in this case Sheet1.B1) to the cell next to SelectRange (in this case Sheet2.B1).

For this example, I just created a blank sheet with 1-500 listed in Sheet1.A1:A500 and Sheet2.A1:A500 and abc,def,ghi repeated throughout Sheet1.B2:B500.

I don't think this will do exactly what you want, but should give you a base to tweak from, as I know you mentioned about having certain absolute references on Sheet 1.

```
Sub insurance()

Dim CompareRange As Range, SelectRange As Range, x As Variant, y As Variant

Set SelectRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:A500")
Set CompareRange = Sheet2.Range("A1:A500")

For Each x In SelectRange
For Each y In CompareRange
If x = y Then x.Offset(0, 1).Copy y.Offset(0, 1)
Next y
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: That unfortunately didn't work. I'll put context above.

Comment: Given the context, I think it might make more sense for you to build a pivot table rather than use VBA to update these on a regular basis. You'll likely to run into issues if the only connecting unique identifier between the two sheets is the AccountID though, even if you did write a VBA script for it as it won't necessarily line up the properly Insurance Claim from that AccountID with the correct claim (assuming that there's more information there such as the Amount etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the help, Kris. I appreciate it. The pivot table won't work. Previously I've been filtering on insurance claim and copying the data. This takes quite a long time and I was hoping to automate it. Perhaps this just isn't something that can be automated.

Comment: A pivot table could hypothetically work, but would require a redesign of how the core data set works to create a unique key on each sheet to connect them together. This unique key could be made up of multiple values which could be automated which a custom column of =A1+B1+C3 etc. This could be date, time, account number, etc.